# Xcode v12.5 - Build error on opening SQlite DB

Tags: ios, react-native, sqlite, swift5, xcode12.5

Working on a React-Native project, after upgrading the Xcode from v12.4 to 12.5 getting a build error. Used to work perfectly in Xcode v12.4

I have narrowed down to the line which causes this build error:

```
var db: OpaquePointer?
let _path = path ?? "widgetdb.sqlite3";
sqlite3_open(_path, &db) <-- This is the culprit!
```

Error log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift._ArrayBuffer._copyContents(initializing: Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A>) -> (Swift.IndexingIterator<Swift._ArrayBuffer<A>>, Swift.Int)", referenced from:
      generic specialization <serialized, Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Int8>> of Swift._copyCollectionToContiguousArray<A where A: Swift.Collection>(A) -> Swift.ContiguousArray<A.Element> in SQLiteDatabase.o
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run into similar issue today, but the error was with Alamofire

In my case I resolved it by removing

```
"\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\""
```

from LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS in Project Search Paths

Comment: Thanks a ton!
Worked in my case as well!!

Comment: Are you sure we need to remove this?